# Redactor - Fixed toolbar not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, redactor

According to the Redactor docs regarding [fixed toolbar settings](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/toolbar/#setting-toolbarFixed), I can pass the toolbarFixed flag as true, and the toolbar should stay at the top of the viewport as the user scrolls down, however this isn't working on mobile.

My suspicion as to why it doesn't work on mobile is: the source code is listening for a scroll event, when on mobile it would be a drag event. Has anyone encountered this? If so what was your work around?

Currently running version 10.1.3

Suspect line:

```
$(this.opts.toolbarFixedTarget).on('scroll.redactor.' + this.uuid, $.proxy(this.toolbar.observeScroll, this));
```

Comment: The demo on their website does not work on mobile with toolbarFixed. I think you'd better contact them directly via their support forum.

Comment: Unfortunately they charge another $100 support fee on top of the initial $99 license. Not that it's a lot of $$, just wanted to see if anyone has had any other issues. TBH redactor is decent, but did take some severe customization to make it usable as the primary editor on shouttag.com

Comment: I'm using redactor in a modal (fixed) and can't even rely on their toolbarFixed. I agree that it is not the most robust piece of software but arguably one of the best options and they move rather fast at updating it. If you find an alternative though, I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: Friggin' redactor, man. It's great when it works, but it really requires an evergreen browser.

Have you tried duplicating that line and changing the event type to drag?  It's been a long time since I looked at redactor's code, but it's strange to me that it's not just using fixed positioning.  Seems like it could just attach the toolbar container directly to the body tag, set the style to `position:fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: <whatever>' and let the browser handle things like it's designed to do.

Comment: I'll give her a try. I did try to hack in a drag listener but to no avail. I'll try the fixed position and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in version 2!

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the product and should be fixed on their end. However, if they happen to take too long to fix the issue you can always write your own script for positioning the toolbar which would not be so hard given that the toolbar exists in the same context as the rest of the page with no iframes involved.